# VBA deleting rows based on cell vale

Tags: vba, excel

[image]I've written the following code where i want to find the value "BEST Cards Raised:" in column B and where ever this value is delete this and all subsequent rows with data in column B.

I thought what i've written would work but its currently deleting all rows and I cant figure it out :(

```
Dim lastRow As Long, found As Range
With ActiveSheet

    Set found = .Range("B1:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Find("BEST Cards Raised:")
    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        lastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                              After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                              Lookat:=xlPart, _
                              LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                              MatchCase:=False).Row
        If lastRow >= found.Row Then
            Debug.Print .Rows(found.Row & ":" & lastRow).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Do you mean to delete the row that has BEST in as well as the rows after?

Comment: i did, but it doesn't really matter as that row won't affect what im doing with the data afterwards, its important all rows after disappear and would be nice if that value is gone too but not important at all

Comment: Doesn't your code do what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If also deleting the row where found then perhaps try the following:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim lastRow As Long, found As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<your sheet

        Set found = .Range("B1:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Find("BEST Cards Raised:")
        If Not found Is Nothing Then
            lastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                                  After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                                  Lookat:=xlPart, _
                                  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                  MatchCase:=False).Row
            If lastRow >= found.Row Then
                .Rows(found.Row & ":" & lastRow).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Post debugging

```
Dim lastRow As Long, foundRow As Variant
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet8")
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    foundRow = Application.Match("BEST Cards Raised:", .Range("B1:B" & lastRow), 0)
    If IsError(foundRow) Then Exit Sub
    If lastRow >= foundRow Then .Rows(foundRow & ":" & lastRow).EntireRow.Delete
End With
```

Comment: do i need the option explicit? as this doesn't delete any rows :') if so i get an error on the rest of my code when i try to add this in

Comment: You should always have it. If VBE is now complaining it means you have errors elsewhere in your code that should be fixed e.g. undeclared variables, or mispelt variables.

Comment: these all work though until i add option explicit :'(

Comment: What is the error message it is giving you? Option Explicit is best practice and whilst your code maybe working witth out it, you may have bugs just waiting to bite.

Comment: i get variable not defined (refers to code i've already written)

Comment: There you go. Means you have variables you should have declared and are implicitly being passed as variants. Your choice - you can fix them or remove the Option Explicit.

Comment: I tried to remove the option but then no rows delete (i have about 50 pages of code so don't fancy going through renaming everything else) this is the last bit i need to solve for my reporting to work. 

Could it be an issue if the cell where "best" is located is a merged cell? cell reference is currently B7 but will move about in column b depening on when report is run.

Comment: Not really as works fine for me. What happens if in my code you put debug.print  .Rows(found.Row & ":" & lastRow).Address ? What is printed out?

Comment: nothing :/ still nothing is deleted ... i have no idea why. 
alternatively if its something wrong with the data could we try to delete everything in column A when Sales region is found for the second time? 
im thinking this could be my data as the values come from a webpage

Comment: There should be an address printed out in the immediate window provided the If block is entered i.e. the lastRow is >= to the row where search term found.

Comment: nope nothing other than the webaddress where i took my info from, i've updated the code up top to show what i've used, encase i did something wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179553/discussion-between-qharr-and-pgd15).

Comment: @PGD15 - Hold the phone... If your code fails to delete the rows just because you removed the "Option Explicit", then my guess is that you've got variable names walking over each other.  "Option Explicit" forces you to explicitly declare all your variables, which prevents you from re-using variable names and makes sure that the datatype for your variables is correct for what that variable is being used for.  By not explicitly declaring your variables, you are allowing confusion about what a variable is supposed to be used for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (comments in code):

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    'determine where to start deleting rows
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If Trim(ws.Cells(i, 2).Value) = "BEST Cards Raised:" Then Exit For
    Next
    'delete all rows from last to found row, looping backwards
    For j = lastRow To i Step -1
        ws.Rows(j).Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: this deleted everything on the tab :'( need a combination between your and Qharr's

Comment: @PGD15 Could you share the example data in sheet? Because it's working fine on my PC, it deletes every thing after "BEST Cards Raised:" is found.

Comment: I added a screenshot but had to blank the data out as its confidential its from a secure webpage and pasted into excel

Comment: @PGD15 Is B2 merged with any other cells?

Comment: no? but where has b2 come from? :') if you mean the best card raised: cell than the answer is yes, merged through to Q2

Comment: @PGD15 Thank you for understanding :) I don't know how I came up with B2. Try updated answer. If it doesn't work, please tell me what `MsgBox Cells(6, 2).Value` shows.

Comment: @MichalTurzyn I cant get your code to work i need to change "sheet1" to active sheet. though i've already used a line at the start where i set "destsheet" = activesheet. 
so i need to write something like Dim destsheet (i've also used i before for another bit of code so can i use iii or does it need to be i?)

Comment: @PGD15 You have to test it yourself. If it doesn't work with `i` then choose some other name for that variable. And change `sheet1` to your actual worksheet name. Then it should work.

Comment: i did try but i get an error because i cant use a sheet name like "sheet1" as each time i run the macro it's different due to sheets being added in

Comment: @PGD15 Then you always should put there your sheet name. Anyway, Does it work finally?

Comment: does now! worked it through Qharr in chat as i had an issue!

Comment: @PGD15 If my answer helped you should accept it and optionally upvote.